# How do I interpret the signature of read_until and what is AsyncRead + BufRead in Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to understand asynchronous I/O in Rust. The following code is based on a snippet from Katharina Fey's 
[Jan 2019 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_wnB9ibCMg&feature=youtu.be&t=1078) which works for me:

```
use futures::future::Future;
use std::io::BufReader;
use tokio::io::*;

fn main() {
    let reader = BufReader::new(tokio::io::stdin());
    let buffer = Vec::new();

    println!("Type something:");
    let fut = tokio::io::read_until(reader, b'\n', buffer)
        .and_then(move |(stdin, buffer)| {
            tokio::io::stdout()
                .write_all(&buffer)
                .map_err(|e| panic!(e))
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!(e));

    tokio::run(fut);
}
```

Before finding that code, I attempted to figure it out from the [`read_until`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/io/fn.read_until.html) documentation.

How do I interpret the signature of `read_until` to use it in a code sample like the one above?

```
pub fn read_until<A>(a: A, byte: u8, buf: Vec<u8>) -> ReadUntil<A> 
where
    A: AsyncRead + BufRead,
```

Specifically, how can I know from reading the documentation, what are the parameters passed into the `and_then` closure and the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Parameters to `and_then`

Unfortunately the standard layout of the Rust documentation makes futures quite hard to follow.

Starting from the [`read_until`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/io/fn.read_until.html) documentation you linked, I can see that it returns `ReadUntil<A>`.  I'll click on that to go to the [`ReadUntil` documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/io/struct.ReadUntil.html).

This return value is described as:

> A future which can be used to easily read the contents of a stream into a vector until the delimiter is reached.

I would expect it to implement the `Future` trait — and I can see that it does. I would also assume that the `Item` that the future resolves to is some sort of vector, but I don't know exactly what, so I keep digging:

1. First I look under "Trait implementations" and find `impl<A> Future for ReadUntil<A>`
2. I click the `[+]` expander

Finally I see the associated `type Item = (A, Vec<u8>)`. This means it's a `Future` that's going to return a pair of values: the `A`, so it is presumably giving me back the original `reader` that I passed in, plus a vector of bytes.

When the future resolves to this tuple, I want to attach some additional processing with `and_then`. This is part of the `Future` trait, so I can scroll down further to find that function.

```rust
fn and_then<F, B>(self, f: F) -> AndThen<Self, B, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> B,
    B: IntoFuture<Error = Self::Error>,
    Self: Sized,
```

The function `and_then` is documented as taking two parameters, but `self` is passed implicitly by the compiler when using dot syntax to *chain* functions, which tells us that we can write `read_until(A, '\n', buffer).and_then(...)`.  The second parameter in the documentation, `f: F`, becomes the first argument passed to `and_then` in our code.

I can see that `f` is a closure because the type `F` is shown as `FnOnce(Self::Item) -> B` (which if I click through links to the [Rust book closure chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ch13-01-closures.html).

The closure `f` that is passed in takes `Self::Item` as the parameter. I just found out that `Item` is `(A, Vec<u8>)`, so I expect to write something like `.and_then(|(reader, buffer)| { /* ... /* })`

### `AsyncRead` + `BufRead`

This is putting constraints on what type of reader can be read from. The created [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) implements [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html).

Helpfully, Tokio provides [an implementation of `AsyncRead` for `BufReader`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.21/tokio/prelude/trait.AsyncRead.html#impl-AsyncRead-for-BufReader%3CT%3E) so we don't have to worry about it, we can just go ahead and use the `BufReader`.

Comment: So helpful!  The breadcrumb trail helped me see [+] and follow the parameter reference syntax.  I've suggested an edit to clarify for future readers, and also test my understanding of the closure syntax -- thank you!